# Creating a shared support email in GSuite

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace, gmail-addons, google-groups

Currently the small business I work for has a support email address setup as the following: support@mybusinessdomain.com (changed domain for anonymity).

We need to make it so that multiple people can manage this email address, and the way we have it currently setup is causing some issues.

The way it is currently setup is that all emails are forwarded to myself and three other coworkers that manage the support emails that come in, and each of us have setup the following rule:

```
"Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "BusinessDomain Support", Never send it to Spam"
```

So we get all of the emails sent to that label, they skip our inbox and we delegate/respond from there. This was causing issues with my coworkers responding to the same emails and has our customers replying to our actual work email addresses rather than the support email.

We setup a process/procedure to make sure my coworkers and I were only answering things once, and to solve the problem of customers responding to the wrong email address we added the support@mybusinessdomain.com email as a "Send mail as" for each of us. However, now we are all sending emails from the same email address and it is a bit confusing as to who responded AND all sent emails are showing in our sent folder.

So, what is the best way to setup this support email so that multiple people can manage it and so that customers that reply to emails sent are always sent to support@mybusinessdomain.com?

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [use a group as a collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430).

> Collaborative inboxes are especially useful for technical support or
>   customer service teams. For example, you could create a group with the
>   address **support**@***your-domain.com***. You could then add your
>   support staff as group members, and allow people outside your
>   organization to send messages to the group. Your support staff would
>   then receive customer messages and take any of the following actions:
>
> - Assign responsibility for topics to group members
> - Mark topics as resolved
> - Edit tags associated with topics
> - Filter topics according to tag, resolution status, or assignee